# JAVA Arraylist unexpected output

Tags: java, list, arraylist

Expected output : 
Cell-1 Cell-2
Cell-3 Cell-4

But the output that I am getting is : 
Cell-3 Cell-4
Cell-3 Cell-4

Why is this happening?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {
public static void main(String... a) {
    String[][] var1 = new String[] []{{"Cell-1","Cell-2"},{"Cell-3","Cell-4"}};
    ArrayList<String> r = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> var = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

    //Insering data into the ArrayList.
    for(String[] row : var1){
        r.clear();
        for(String data : row){
            r.add(data);
        }
        var.add(r);
    }

    //Print data to console.
    for(ArrayList<String> r1 : var){
        for(String cell : r1)
            System.out.print(cell+" ");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

}
`

Comment: This is not an answer. You should use `List<List<String>>` instead.

Comment: @adarshr : What is the advantage of using List<List<String>> over ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not unexpected at all: you add the same object, namely `ArrayList r`, to the `ArrayList var` twice. First, you add it when it has `Cell-1 Cell-2`, then you clear it, and then you add it with `Cell-3 Cell-4`. The problem is, when you call `r.clear()`, the array list that you added to `var` gets cleared as well.

You need to create a new `ArrayList` instead of clearing the existing one to fix this problem: replace `r.clear()` with `r = new ArrayList<String>()`, and the problem will go away.